# Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password

Tags: google-cloud-sql

One of my client repetitively tried to login to Google Cloud SQL Instance. So I checked sql logs which mentioned following errors :

1. "Logon Login failed for user 'a'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided"
2. "Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password"

Actually My google cloud SQL Service was having multiple connection requests so the connection pool was full. In that period the client sent multiple login requests which seems to be the reason that
his access might have been blocked because other clients and me are not facing this issue with the same SQL credentials. I checked firewall on VM and Authorized Network on Google Cloud SQL. There seems to be no issue there.

What could be the solution for the above problem ?